# WEB API With database Post Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to make an API Post method where I insert data into the database.

The database has 3 fields: One field has default values given by the database, one I have to insert with a new `Guid.NewGuid()` method, and one is inserted by the user.

How can I do this? Never seen anything like this in a tutorial.

If you can give me an example I will appreciate.

I'm new in web APIs and have seen a bunch of tutorials since Wednesday and can't reach a solution.

EDIT:
Here is my code:

`public HttpResponseMessage Post(Company value)
        {
            try
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    bd.Companies.Add(value);
                    bd.SaveChanges();
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Invalid Model");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }`

How can i put a `Guid.NewGuid()`in this code to give a value to one of my fields?

EDIT2: My class to receive the values from Post

`public class CompanyPostViewModel  : Company
    {
        public static Guid Guid.NewGuid(); -->how can i do this?
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: What part are you stuck with? Making the Api? Writing to the database? Making the GUID?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an example, that fully goes from the front-end, to using WEB API [Post], to writing to the database, please see the following [site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/inserting-Asp-Net-form-data-into-database-using-web-api/). It should provide you enough context to complete what you are trying to accomplish. If this is insufficient, please post your current code, and where you are having any issues.